# Google Cloud Speech Async Streaming GRPC tunnel closed by Google

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Trying to connect our contact center to Google Cloud Speech via gRPC on C++, using async streaming.
The logs we pass down the configuration is below:

```
@2018-08-01 07:13:11,316||FINEST|MediaMgr|2601||ProcessMessage - Message 
Content: type: StartCloudRecognition
endpointID: 5
config: { "provider": "google", "profanity-filter": false, "chunkSize": 8192, 
"phrases": [] }
```

Then we start writing the content in:

```
@2018-08-01 07:13:12,101||FINEST|Tele|2673|FileName=media/audio/CloudEndpoint.cpp,LineNumber=317|CheckStatus() get 2|MPP227####
@2018-08-01 07:13:12,151||FINEST|Tele|2673|FileName=media/audio/CloudEndpoint.cpp,LineNumber=317|CheckStatus() get 1|MPP227####
@2018-08-01 07:13:12,151||FINEST|Tele|2673|FileName=media/audio/CloudEndpoint.cpp,LineNumber=325|GSRProvider::CheckStatus: EndpointID=5 Got event tag=0x1899f98 ok=true state=1|MPP227####
@2018-08-01 07:13:12,151||FINEST|Tele|2673|FileName=media/audio/CloudEndpoint.cpp,LineNumber=317|CheckStatus() get 1|MPP227####
@2018-08-01 07:13:12,151||FINEST|Tele|2673|FileName=media/audio/CloudEndpoint.cpp,LineNumber=325|GSRProvider::CheckStatus: EndpointID=5 Got event tag=0x1899f94 ok=true state=2|MPP227####
@2018-08-01 07:13:12,151||FINEST|Tele|2673|FileName=media/audio/CloudEndpoint.cpp,LineNumber=317|CheckStatus() get 1|MPP227####
@2018-08-01 07:13:12,151||FINEST|Tele|2673|FileName=media/audio/CloudEndpoint.cpp,LineNumber=325|GSRProvider::CheckStatus: EndpointID=5 Got event tag=0x1899f8c ok=true state=4|MPP227####
```

the final line of the snippet logs state = 4 is write_tag, so our app do write data through the gRPC tunnel.

and little bit later we got lines like :

```
@2018-08-01 07:13:12,283||FINEST|Tele|2673|FileName=media/audio/CloudEndpoint.cpp,LineNumber=325|GSRProvider::CheckStatus: EndpointID=5 Got event tag=0x1899f90 ok=false state=3|MPP227####
```

this event comes in as a read_tag and the ok tag is being set to google to false, from gRPC it means the tunnel being closed. So the speech recognition process stop before the tester even try to speak some meaningful content.

we have 2 lab sharing same build on the same area, one in ireland which always failed the test, one at usa always pass the same test.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Find out some packet we sent to google is corrupted.